# Parse XML and display it in an AlertDialog in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-alertdialog

I have this .xml file with countries and their countrycodes in them. This is how it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<landen>
<land>
   <naam>Afghanistan</naam>
   <code>AF</code>
</land>
<land>
   <naam>Albani�</naam>
   <code>AL</code>
</land>
<land>
   <naam>Algerije</naam>
   <code>DZ</code>
</land>
<land>
</landen>
```

Now I want people to choose one country out of an list. I though an AlertDialog would be nice to display everything.

The way i get the values out of my xml-file is like this:

```
protected ArrayList<Land> getLanden() {
    ArrayList<Land> lijst = new ArrayList<Land>();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(getAssets().open("landenlijst.xml"));
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("land");
        for (int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++) {
            Node node = nl.item(i);

            Land land = new Land();

            land.land = Xml.innerHtml(Xml.getChildByTagName(node, "naam"));
            land.landcode = Xml.innerHtml(Xml.getChildByTagName(node, "code"));
            lijst.add(land);
        }
        Log.d("Gabug","Klaar met parsen");
        Log.d("Gabug","Landen: " + lijst);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lijst;
}
```

And I use this to make my AlertDialog:

```
public void KiesLandMenu(){
        ArrayList<Land> alleLanden = getLanden();
        final CharSequence[] items = alleLanden.toArray(new CharSequence[alleLanden.size()]);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Kies land");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                switch (item){
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

I don't know if this works as DDMS returns some bytecode or something when i Log it. And after that it Force Closes because of ArrayStoreException..

Now my question is; is this the best way to do this? if yes, how can I fix the ArrayStoreException? If no, what are better ways to let my user choose a country (a whole new view maybe)?
Furthermore, how can I register what country someone tapped?

EDIT:

I slightly changed the sample code below and I get an NullPointerException now..

```
public void KiesLandMenu(){
    ArrayAdapter<Land> arrAdapter;
    ArrayList<Land> alleLanden = getLanden();
    arrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Land>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, alleLanden);

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.layout.lijstview);
    list.setAdapter(arrAdapter);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Log.e("item clicked", String.valueOf(position));
        }
    });
}
```

The NullPointerException is at `list.setAdapter(arrAdapter);`

Comment: (ListView)findViewById(R.layout.lijstview) is returning null.  It's R.id.lijstview.

Comment: I created lijstview.xml in the layout folder, and it doesn't give me an error in Eclipse. While it DOES give me an error when i put R.id.lijstview there.

Comment: You should set up your layout in onCreate first.  I will edit my answer below.

Comment: Maybe an extremely dumb question, but how do I make a dialog layout.

Comment: Oh it's just like any other layout, I just meant by that "The layout you will use for your dialog". You can use the XML layout in my answer as the dialog layout.  In my answer, main.xml will be the layout of your activity, the one the user will see once the activity starts.  Then withList.xml will be the layout of the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a layout with a ListView, then set that layout in your onCreate.  To make the list, you can do something like:

```
public class RunTestProject extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  //whatever you want your layout to be
}

// getLanden() implementation goes here


public void KiesLandMenu(){
    ArrayList<Land> alleLanden = getLanden();
    arrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, alleLanden);

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Kies land");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.withList); // The dialog layout
    ListView list = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.list); //note that it's not simply findViewById
    list.setAdapter(arrAdapter);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Log.e("item clicked", String.valueOf(position));
        }
    });

    dialog.show();      
}
```

}

When the user chooses on an item, you can see in the log that the item's position in the array is shown.

Your layout file can be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
         /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably extend `AlertDialog` and give it a `ListView` as a view.  Then bind the `ListView` to an `ListAdapter` which uses your `ArrayList`.

Edit:

```
ListView lv = new ListView(context);
ArrayAdapter aa = new ListAdapter(context, viewid, lijst);
lv.setAdapter(aa);
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog(context);
ad.setView(lv);
```

There is a bit more work than that though.  You need to specify `viewid` which is the `View` representing each item in the `ListView`.

The sdk reference is very good you know.

Comment: Could you maybe show me how to do that, because i don't understand what you're saying there :)

Comment: I want SAMPLE code. I just don't understand what you're saying so i ask for an example. jeez...

Answer (score 0):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
            .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_single_choice)
            .setSingleChoiceItems(<ListAdapter> or CharaSequnce[] , 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked on a radio button do some stuff */
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked Yes so do some stuff */
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked No so do some stuff */
                }
            })
           .create();
```

**Note :**
Please see [This link to Api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28java.lang.CharSequence%5b%5d,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29)  for Bold text mentioned below

.setSingleChoiceItems(**CharacterSequnce[]** , 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()....

Hope this helps . Thanks :)